# multiple select result in MySQL depend on other select

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have database like this:

[image: schema]

For example, a user requests all `posts` data with `posts.post_id = 1`. Now I want to get additional data from other tables:

- some fields from table `posts` with `post_id = 1`
- all fileds from table `postmeta` with `post_id = 1`
- some fields from table `users` which depend on `posts.user_id` where `post_id = 1`
- all fields from table `files` which have a relation to `post_id = 1`
- some fields from table `terms` where have a relation to `post_id = 1`

In PHP I can simply run 5 queries to get this information, but I guess this is not the best way because MySQL is able to perform this faster.

**Update detail:**

```
-- select from posts
SELECT
    posts.post_id,
    posts.post_title,
    posts.post_name,
    posts.post_content,
    posts.post_status,
    posts.post_type,
    posts.post_modified_gmt,
    posts.post_date_gmt,
    posts.post_mime_type,
    posts.user_id
FROM
    posts
WHERE
    posts.post_id = 1

--select from postmeta
SELECT
    postmeta.postmeta_value,
    postmeta.postmeta_key,
    postmeta.postmeta_id
FROM
    postmeta
WHERE
    postmeta.post_id = 1


SELECT
    files.file_size,
    files.file_type,
    files.file_name,
    files.file_id
FROM
    files
INNER JOIN file_relationships ON files.file_id = files.file_id
WHERE
    file_relationships.post_id = 1

--select from terms
SELECT
    terms.term_id,
    terms.term_name,
    terms.term_slug,
    terms.term_taxonomy,
    terms.term_description,
    terms.term_group,
    terms.term_parent,
    terms.term_count
FROM
    term_relationships
INNER JOIN terms ON term_relationships.term_id = terms.term_id
WHERE
    term_relationships.post_id = 1

--select from users , users.user_id depend on posts.user_id 
SELECT
    users.user_id,
    users.user_name,
    users.user_email,
    users.user_nicename,
    users.user_password,
    users.user_displayname,
    users.user_role,
    users.user_bio
FROM
    users
WHERE
    users.user_id = 1
```

this is query i run to get information with PHP,
[database + data](http://bayanbox.ir/id/3007353188755245356?download)

Is there a way to do this using MySQL only?

Comment: You should read up on SQL `JOIN`s.

Comment: i know little MySQL `JOIN`, i write query but result is not seems good, i get 4 record, contain `posts` field(repeat in 4 record) and `postmeta` field. this is bad for performance, right?

Comment: Please add some sample content and the desired result by the given sample with an explanation why this is the desired result.

Comment: First, get a correct query for your problem. You might be surprised how clever MySQL can be to improve performance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single query isn't always better than multiple ones. In this case I recommend combining only your 1 to 1 relationships but keeping separate queries for your many to 1 relationships because if a single post has 3 terms and 2 files joining both many to 1 relationships would produce 6 rows.

Select post, user and postmeta data

```
select * from posts p
join postmeta pm on pm.post_id = p.post_id
join users u on u.user_id = p.user_id
where p.post_id = 1
```

Select files

```
select f.* from files f
join file_relationships fr on fr.file_id = f.file_id
join posts p on p.post_id = fr.post_id
where p.post_id = 1
```

Select terms

```
select t.* from terms t
join term_relationships tr on tr.term_id = t.term_id
join posts p on p.post_id = tr.post_id
where p.post_id = 1
```

Comment: cause only `users` with `posts` have 1 on 1 relation, then i have run 4 query for get this data?

Comment: @123 in that case yes there would be 4 queries

Answer (score 1):

This should be all the JOINs you need, modify the SELECT list as desired.

```
select p.post_id,
       p.post_title,
       p.user_id,
       u.user_name,
       u.user_email,
       pm.*,
       f.*
  from posts p
  join postmeta pm
    on p.post_id = pm.post_id
  join users u
    on p.user_id = u.user_id
  join file_relationships fr
    on p.post_id = fr.post_id
  join files f
    on fr.file_id = f.file_id
```

The * indicates 'all columns' from the table with the indicated alias.

Comment: if i use `JOIN` i have 10 or more repetitive column, this is not good for performance, is possible other way get that field?

Comment: Do you mean columns or rows?

Comment: You can bring back whatever columns you want. In your question you didn't say what columns you wanted, you only said "some columns". Either modify the select list to bring back the columns you want or specify the columns you want in your question and I'll change it to bring back only those columns.

Comment: If you did mean rows, then some of the tables' fields have a one to many relationship with each other. In that case we need to know how you want to aggregate. If you don't know what you want, example data and expected results would be helfpful.

Comment: Then there is a one to many relationship between some of the tables. For instance a single post may have 5 files. As a result, boom, you have 5 repeated rows for that post based on the join to that table alone (one for each file of that post). If you want only one row to a post, you have to aggregate in one way or another. Do you want the first file for the post? The last file for the post? etc. If you provide sample data and expected results we can help further. We have to know how you want to aggregate each situation that is one to many, and what those situations are.

Comment: yes,each post have many file and each post have many terms, database and data added.

Comment: @123 so which of the rows do you want to be returned in those cases? The first file? Last file? There is a legitimate reason for there being 2+ rows when there are 2+ files to a post...

Comment: i want all of rows, i think i do @FuzzyTree way